# Add new program to Supervisord from php

Tags: php, supervisord

I am looking for a way to **add a new program(job)** to supervisord from php which **does not exist in supervisor's config file.**

It could look like this:

```
$supervisord = new SupervisordMgr(...);

$process = new Prod('path/to/worker-x.sh');
$supervisord->addProcess($process);

$process->getStatus();
$process->stop();
```

Supervisord has an API, so it should be a way to do this.

Is there anything out there?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like it's not possible to add a new program to Supervisord using the xml-rpc api, only to start/stop already defined ones.

Answer (score 0):

Make an entry for the process "[program:x,]" you want to start dynamically, in supervisord.conf and issue "supervisorctl update" command afterwards. The newly added program will be started without restarting/stopping rest of the unchanged programs/processes.

Comment: Thanks, but the question says: "Using an API"

Comment: @Tibor I see. There is nothing out-of-box like this but you can always automate this as a script or via programming :)